# mysql installer 8.0.11 web community refuses to initialise database

Tags: mysql

Am trying to install mysql using the mysql installer(web) but when it got to the

```
Apply Configuration -> initialising Database
```

section it stopped saying,

> The configuration for MySql server 8.0.11 has failed.

I checked on the log tab and this is what I saw pertaining to the initialising the database section...

```
Beginning configuration step: Initializing Database
Attempting to run MySQL Server with --initialize-insecure option...
Starting process for MySQL Server 8.0.11...
Starting process with command: C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe --defaults-file="C:\ProgramData\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\my.ini" --console --initialize-insecure=on...
2018-07-21T17:38:19.967888Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011071] [Server] Unknown suffix '.' used for variable 'lower_case_table_names' (value '0.0')
2018-07-21T17:38:19.968016Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-011071] [Server] C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 8.0\bin\mysqld.exe: Error while setting value '0.0' to 'lower_case_table_names'
2018-07-21T17:38:19.968163Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2018-07-21T17:38:19.968386Z 0 [Note] [MY-010120] [Server] Binlog end
Process for mysqld, with ID 6744, was run successfully and exited with code 1.
Failed to start process for MySQL Server 8.0.11.
Database initialization failed.
Ended configuration step: Initializing Database
```

Comment: let me know if it worked :)

Comment: I just re download  the offline package and reinstall it. But is unable (mysql) to start up automatically after retarting the system. Also, it does not connect to workbench and I don't know if that is due to me installing apache server and also installing mysql as **development machine**. Also mysql router refuses to execute

Answer (score 0):

It happened to me too, It's a bug  [mysql.com thread](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=91615)

I solved that, download the complete version and you will not have any problems :)

[image]

or alternative go to **my.ini**, and change

```
lower_case_table_names=0.0
```

to

`lower_case_table_names=0`